# c++ armadillo with openblas on windows 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, blas, armadillo

I am trying to install and use Armadillo with OpenBlas on Windows8 / Visual Studio.

I managed to install Armadillo and run a small program without problem. However it is using the default supplied-with-Armadillo 32 bit LAPACK and BLAS binaries which are too slow. I witnessed on linux that the speed improvement when using OpenBlas (compared to default Armadillo or BLAS) is huge when multiplying large matrices and would like to be able to use it on Win8 as well.

When I try to replace BLAS lib with OpenBlas from there:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.8/
and try to link with libopenblas.lib, I get a lot of blas-related unresolved external (again, not the case when I link with the armadillo supplied blas_win32_MT.lib) and really have no idea how to solve the problem.

Any help much appreciated.

JPN

Comment: while not exactly OpenBLAS, this link will probably help out:
http://ylzhao.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/blas-lapack-precompiled-binaries-for.html

Comment: Yes thanks, it was a 32 - 64 bit compatibility issue.